# Filtered product of lists without repetitions

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I need an efficient solution to find all combinations without repetitions of a given lists. It has to work like this:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [3, 4, 5]
combinations(l1, l2) = [(2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 5), (1, 3), (3, 5)]
```

The important thing is that I could use it for an arbitrary number of lists and in a very efficient way (preferably using itertools).

My current implementation is way too slow:

```
import itertools

def combinations(*all_lists: tuple[list[int]]):
    lists_product = itertools.product(*all_lists)
    res = set()

    for x in lists_product:
        if len(set(x)) == len(all_lists):
            x = tuple(sorted(x))
            res.add(x)

    return list(res)
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: @Marcus permutations act on a single iterable. Howerver what he seems to want is a way to combine items from multiple iterables

Comment: @Marcus I don't need permutations, I need combinations.

Comment: Combinations are a different thing than what you are describing. Combinations are among elements of a single set. What you are looking for is the product filtered to not include duplicates. I do not see how you could do it any "faster" (using python)

Comment: @Matteo Zanoni yes, you have right, that aren't combinations.

Comment: Doesn't itertools.product do that for you? Your for loop seems to simply sort them in a different way.  If you want an arbitrary number of lists just make your function return list_produc, or just use itertools directly because you have to give each list as input anyway.

Comment: That should take maybe a microsecond, how is that too slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which is a little faster :

```
def combinations_2(*all_lists: tuple[list[int]]):
    len_all_list = len(all_lists)
    lists_product = list(itertools.product(*all_lists))
    fset = set(map(frozenset,lists_product))
    list_filter = list(map(sorted, list(filter(lambda x: len(x) == len_all_list, fset))))
    res_2 = list(map(tuple, list_filter))
    return res_2
```

As your result `res` is from a `set()` which is an unordered data structure. So I sorted the two outputs for comparing.

```
import random

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 20, 25, 30]
l1 = random.choices(values,k=100)
l2 = random.choices(values,k=100)

res = combinations(l1, l2)
res_2 = combinations_2(l1, l2)

res_temp = sorted(res, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
res_2_temp = sorted(res_2, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))

print(res_temp == res_2_temp)
```

Which gives the result

> True

Then the running time :

```
%timeit combinations(l1, l2)
```

> 7.1 ms ± 437 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%timeit combinations_2(l1, l2)
```

> 2.56 ms ± 109 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)