# Python itertools.product intermediate test or alternate method

Tags: python, iteration, permutation, python-itertools

I am trying to use Python itertools.product to come up with all possible combinations of a long list of long lists. I do have criteria that no element of any list can be repeated. (Possible values are integers 0 to 349.)

The list to iterate contains 50 other lists.

Each of the 50 lists is shaped somewhere between (1,2) up to maxs of (57,2), (18,3), (49,4), and (5,5). These sizes will change as input data changes, but this gives you an idea of what I am dealing with to start.

```
Combo = list(itertools.product(*test))

remove_index = []
for i in range(0,len(Combo)): # look for duplicates in iterations, then remove
    if DupTest(Combo[i]) == True:
        remove_index.append(i)
    for j in sorted(remove_index, reverse = True):
        del Combo[j]
```

These are too large to be able to run itertools.product without crashing. I tried breaking it up into smaller groups (I can process 10 groups of 5 each pretty easily), but then I still can't process the next iteration with those results.

Any ideas for how to test for duplicate elements before creating the list of all the products?

Comment: A similar question, where the accepted answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76579762/filtered-product-of-lists-without-repetitions/76580505

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.product` isn't what crashes your computer -- it's the `list()` around it. `itertools.product` returns a generator which is evaluated lazily, so it only uses memory for one item at a time. On the other hand, listing out all the combinations in the product requires enough memory for all the items in the product.

You could use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to filter out elements of the product that don't satisfy your criteria:

```
for item in filter(DupTest, itertools.product(*test)):
    print(item)
```

---

Note some unrelated suggestions:

- Usually, you don't need to iterate `for index in range(0, len(lst))` and then access `item = lst[index]`. Instead, get the item directly by `for item in lst`.
- To test if `something` is `True`, just `if something:` is sufficient. You don't need to specify `if something == True`, unless you explicitly want to exclude cases when `something` is a non-boolean [truthy value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/843953)
- As you delete elements from `Combo`, the old indices no longer apply, so you're not deleting the indices you originally intended. For example:

```
>>> lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(lst[3])
3
>>> del lst[2]
>>> print(lst[3])
4
```

<sup>I notice you've reversed the list of indices, so this last point doesn't apply</sup>